# Css transitions behaves weirdly when loaded

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm currently working on a schoolproject and I've been trying out some css-transitions. I'm using the transition property to light up the nav-links in the nav but when the page loads the color of the font and the size change size and color before they quickly transition into the styles I've specified in the css. Do you have any clue what could've caused this? I'm having the same issue with some of the other elements on the page too.
I've tried using the transition on the color property only `transition:color,0.5s;` but then the text turns blue/purpelish for some reason. I've also tried the webkit-prefix but that didn't really help. If I take away the transitions the problem stops.
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the css for the nav

```
 .main-head a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:3em;
    margin:0.5em;
    color:#636363;
    transition:0.5s;
}

.main-head a:hover {
    transition:0.5s;
    color:#eee;
    /*border-bottom:3px solid #eee;
    border-top:3px solid #eee;*/
}
```

And here the page if you want to check it out for yourselves. Pay attention at the top when loading the page and you'll notice the weirdness.

http://albmar13.ddi.hh.se/Laboration%201/index.php

Comment: Your transition syntax for the color property only is incorrect - it should be `transition: color 0.5s;` without the comma. Not sure why the incorrect syntax would cause the text to turn blue/purpleish though.

Comment: You also don't need the `transition` declaration in `a:hover` since you've already specified it for `a`. I'm posting comments because I'm not 100% sure, but let me know if it does fix it for you and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Using the correct syntax as you mentioned fixed the resizing problem, oddly enough the text still turns blue. Thanks for clearing the first part up for me though!

Comment: Which browser are you using ? With Chrome the text doesn't turn blue, it has the color you defined.

Comment: I'm using chrome as well. Just to clarify : The text is looking right for me too, but when the page loads it turns blue for a short period before changing into the color i specified.
*EDIT*
It doesn't turn blue using Safari though. Perhaps it's just a problem with chrome?